# Adafruit 128x64 OLED not turning on

Tags: arduino-uno, display

I ordered a 128x64 pixel OLED display from Adafruit and wired it according to their [guide](https://learn.adafruit.com/monochrome-oled-breakouts/wiring-1-dot-3-128x64). (To an Arduino Uno) I'm using SPI right now and the display will not turn on or do anything. I haven't tried i2C, but I don't think that should make a difference. Maybe I will if nothing else works. I've installed the two [libraries](https://learn.adafruit.com/monochrome-oled-breakouts/arduino-library-and-examples) from the guide and am running the SPI 128x64 example. I've tried to find people with this same issue but I haven't found that much about it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Added pictures. I've used header pins in the past in case anyone is wondering if the connection using these wires isn't good, but the pins did not work either, so it's not a bad connection.

[image]
[image]

Comment: There isn't exactly a question here that has a definite answer. A clear photograph of your setup would help. Please state the exact part number you are using, also the exact sketch that you are testing it with.

Comment: The sketch is an example from the SSD1306 library called "ssd1306_128x64_spi". I will add a picture soon.

Comment: I don't see any soldering in those pictures. You can't just poke wires into holes and hope they'll work. That will be your problem.

Comment: *and wired it according to their guide* - **No you didn't.** See the [this](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/assets/assets/000/002/618/medium640/lcds___displays_solder.jpg?1396785110) - you didn't solder the pins to the board.

Comment: I understand that, but I've done this with a few different sensors in the past and as long as the wires are touching the metal holes there is a connection. I also have set it up exactly how they showed it in the guide just without soldering it.

Comment: When I move the OLED around a little bit the "L" light on the Arduino flashes and I get a notice on my computer saying that a USB device is using too much power. That usually happens when something gets shorted, and I'm not sure why that would be happening here.

Comment: The green and yellow wires on the right look very close. I suggest you install it properly, soldering the wires in and not having large amounts of bare wire which are almost touching. Or at least solder on a header strip as shown in the article. The whole point of using a breadboard is that those pins stick into it.

Comment: These devices are selectable to use SPI or I2C by means of a _soldered-in_ jumper on the back. You can use either but your jumper selection must match. Does yours?

Answer (score 3):

Wiring is your problem. Use soldering iron/solder and flux. Solder your wires. Intermittent connections and accidental shortages with current setup may damage your Arduino and display (and possible your PC/laptop).

Answer (score 0):

I know this issue and understand it well.

If the module is genuine from Adafruit then it should definitely work, if not then once try this library https://github.com/olikraus/U8glib_Arduino

This library has very good documentation. Further if it does not work, attach the picture of wiring.

Answer (score 0):

Its not every time fault of hardware, check the program as well. Load example test program and try again.
https://iotforgeeks.com/i2c-oled-display-not-working/
helped me to resolve the same issue.